# PyCharm warning: "format doesn't require a mapping". What does it mean?

Tags: python, pycharm

For some reason PyCharm warns me about this line of code. I'm just logging the content of a dictionary and gets a warning: *format doesn't require a mapping*

```
self._logger.info('Device channels set: %s' % self._device_channels)
```

The code works just fine and it is not really important, but I'm getting quite a few of these and I don't understand what PyCharm is trying to tell me.

I've googled it but not found anything helpful.

Comment: As a note, [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) recommend `str.format()` over `%` in new code, as it's more powerful and readable.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Using .format() removes the warning. I'll start using it instead, as it apparently is standard in Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that PyCharm warns you for using a simple format string with just a `%s`, while providing a dictionary as the formatting argument. When using named formats (I believe with `%(name)s`), a dictionary argument can be used to fill that format with the value of `argument['name']`.

To avoid the warning, you could try coercing the argument to a simple string yourself, matching the format in the string and the argument you provide:

```
self._logger.info('Device channels set: %s' % str(self._device_channels))
```

Comment: Thanks! Calling str() removes the warning. So does using the new .format() format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `self._device_channels` is a `map` type, and `'%s'` this `string format` needs str

so it will `convert` the `map` type to `str` type. and give you a `warning`

You can cenvert the variable by using `str(self._device_channels)`